# Python: Number of letters in file, simple yet efficient way

Tags: python

I am wondering is there a more efficient way to count all letters in file. I need just letters from a..z and A..Z, so signs like '\n' and '\t' aren't going to count. This is my way but it takes more time than it should.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
in = open("file.txt", "r")
f = in.read().lower()
count = 0
for i in f:
    if i in ascii_lowercase:
        count += 1
print count
```

I know I could use uppercase letter, but does it change anything.

Comment: How did you compare actual running time against how long it "should"?

Comment: Hint: strings have an `.isalpha()` method.

Comment: setting a `letters = set(ascii_lowercase)` will slightly make the `if i in ascii_lowercase` (change to `in letters` ) slightly faster but as @Jongware said, what are you comparing to? how fast do you want it? how slow is slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to modify the contents of the file after reading using `re.sub()`, that could be expensive. Simple built-in `filter()` is what you're looking for.

**UPDATE** this loop, aesthetically pleasing as it may look, is about the slowest of 'm all. @PM 2Ring's `re.sub()` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703746/26083) is the clear winner in terms of speed.

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    print len( filter(lambda x: ('a' <= x <= 'z') or ('A' <= x <= 'Z'), f.read()) )
```

Added a Python lookup-table based approach:

```
# create lookuptable
lut = [0]*256
lut[slice(ord('a'), ord('z'))] = [1] * 26
lut[slice(ord('A'), ord('Z'))] = [1] * 26

with open(fn) as f:
    # sum the matching characters
    print sum([lut[ord(c)] for c in f.read()])
```

Or a `frozenset()` plus generator expression approach:

```
chars = frozenset(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1) + range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)))
with open(fn) as f:
    print sum(1 for c in f.read() if c in chars)
```

Timing results on analyzing ~31MB of binary data using five different approaches:

```
[Mac]Okay->python ~/src/fastcharcount.py 
My original version
7931392
That took  0:00:06.604132  seconds

Python lookuptable
7931392
That took  0:00:02.600067  seconds

re.findall()
7931392
That took  0:00:01.213111  seconds

re.sub()
7931392
That took  0:00:03.737485  seconds

Python frozenset+generator
7931392
That took  0:00:02.202991  seconds
```

Comment: nice python lookup table approach -- I wonder what the memory usage is for findall with your 31MB file?

Comment: Thx. I'm surprised it's even faster than the `re.sub()` approach.

Comment: naa, instead of `len(...)` I just used `sys.getsizeof(...)` and printed that for each approach

Comment: Your `lut` slices have off-by-one errors: they should be `slice(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)` etc. And you can get more speed (and use less RAM) by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension:  `sum(lut[ord(c)] for c in f.read())`. Even better: `sum(1 for c in f.read() if lut[ord(c)])`.

Comment: as PM2Rig pointed out re.sub needs to merge replacements with the original string which neither of findall nor your lut solution do, I guess that's part of the difference. seems a lot though.

Comment: I just noticed that using a `frozenset` for the lookup is _faster_ than my `.isalpha()`solution (at least, on my machine, with my data). Which is a bit weird... I'll add some code to my answer.

Comment: Yup, `frozenset()` combined with generator expression runs in 2.2 seconds on this data set of mine.

Comment: Still impressed that using pure Python (frozenset + generator) you can get below a factor two slowdown compared to C.

Comment: using a generator takes off another 12-15% or so in timing, and uses the least amount of memory. so I guess if you're going for efficiency in terms of time _and_ space, the `lut` is the way to go. the trade-off moving to execution efficiency v.s. coding complexity / programmer skills required ;-)

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." — Donald Knuth

Answer (score 3):

> I need just letters from a..z and A..Z (...) it takes more time than it should.

this should be pretty fast.

```
import re
infile='yourfile.txt'
with open(infile) as f:
    print len(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', f.read()))
```

This approach has several nice properties:

- easy to extend with other patterns
- quick to write
- time and memory efficient

However, it turns out a very efficient approach (in terms of all of time to build, time to run *and* memory used) builds on the idea proposed by PM2Ring and uses a simple string of all characters that should be counted. It's also quite pythonic:

```
# Beautiful is better than ugly.
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
with open(infile) as f:
  return sum(1 for c in f.read() if c in alpha)
```

Note: comparing the above solutions to those with [findall, frozenset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703746/890242) and [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703652/890242) gives the following timing results on a 45KB file with 9.6KB of matching a..zA..Z. As so often with *efficiency questions* there is a trade-off between time and space (YMMV):

```
# findall
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
memory for temporary result: 77.8KB
# frozenset
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop
memory for temporary result: 232B (frozenset)
# string 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop
memory for temporary result: 89B (alpha string)
# sub (my initial solution)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.25 ms per loop
memory for temporary result: 9.2KB
# filter
100 loops, best of 3: 7.7 ms per loop
memory for temporary result: 9.2KB
```

Updates:

- removed numbers. if you need them use the pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`
- use f.read() directly in sub, improves performance by about 70%
- added timing to compare several proposed solutions

If the file is too large to be read in one chunk, process in steps:

```
CHUNK = 1024 * 1024
letter_count = 0
with open(infile) as f:
    while True:
        letter_count += len(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', f.read(CHUNK) if not None else ''))
print letter_count
```

Comment: i dont think he wants numbers but +1 anyways

Comment: If you want efficiency don't modify the text after you've read it from file!

Comment: the `if`less approach will probably win a lot on a big scale

Comment: I'd imagine the `re.sub()` is O(n^2) or worse - because for each character replaced it has to move all characters following it one position to the left before going on to check wether the next character must be substituted. And then: how do you think the `^a-zA-Z` is going to test wether an element in the text matches that pattern?

Comment: @haavee even if it worked like you propose sub() is hardly starting from scratch each time it replaces a character, so it is still in O(n). The pattern takes care of matching, isn't that the purpose of a regex?

Comment: @haavee: `re.sub` only looks at non-overlapping matches, so it doesn't have to continually re-build the string while it's scanning, it can delay that until the whole string's been scanned, but it does have to perform a join process eventually, which makes it slower than simply doing `re.findall`

Comment: @haavee see the timing comparisons, either way regex is definitely the way to go, beats every other solution

Comment: The main reason for that being that the heavy lifting is farmed out to C-code; the regex implementations use lookup tables and that is *fast* indeed.

Comment: I've made a Python native lookup-table based version, which is only twice slower then `re.findall()`. Not bad for an interpreted language *versus* C-code regex. (I've noticed before: Python list indexing is very fast as well, comparatively speaking that is.) Just tested: the `re.sub()` is slower than a Python lookuptable based approach!

Comment: @havee: `str.isalpha` also does its lookup at C speed, but regex wins because it can do its loops at C speed too; other solutions are looping and counting at Python speed. A Python list (like all built-in containers) has its length as an attribute, so the list returned by `re.findall` "magically" has its length computed for it by the regex code that builds the list.

Comment: I've added timing results as well.

Comment: @PM2Ring your statement about `findall` building a list prompted me to profile memory consumption -- as so often there is a tradeoff. Note I don't have a memory profiler at hand so I simply checked the size of the object returned by `findall, filter, sub`.

Comment: Beware that `sys.getsizeof()` can be misleading. Eg for a list it just returns the size of the container object itself and the references it contains, (i.e. C pointers, so 4 or 8 bytes per reference depending on architecture), it _doesn't_ return the size of the actual data pointed to by those references.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy way: you have to loop over the list and add the sizes of the individual list items. Of course, if the list items themselves are containers (apart from strings) then you have to recurse. Fortunately, calling `sys.getsize` on a string _does_ return the correct size.

Comment: ok, on second thoughts for the purpose of comparing space complexity here I guess getsize on findall's result is quite fair as we're really comparing a list of characters/1-sized strings v.s. the string itself (so it's _n_ string objects instead of 1 string of size n) . it seems safe to say that the list will in fact use more memory than a simple string.

Comment: Memory consumption calculations are complicated. :) On a 32 bit machine an empty (Python 2) string takes 24 bytes, each additional char takes 1 byte. (Of course on Python 3 that's going to be bigger, due to Unicode). So it would appear that _n_1 char strings take a lot more RAM than 1 _n_ char string. However, Python caches small strings, so a huge collection of 1 char strings won't actually consume as much RAM as a simple calculation implies.

Comment: Another regex approach that uses less RAM than `.findall` is to use an iterator, but then you have to do the count at Python speed: `sum(1 for m in re.finditer('[a-zA-Z]', data))`, which is about 1.8x slower than the `len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', data))`.

Answer (score 2):

Using string functions:

```
fname = sys.argv[1]

with open(fname) as f:
    data = f.read()

print sum(1 for c in data if c.isalpha())
```

However, this can be made a *lot* faster using Regular Expressions:

```
import re

with open(fname) as f:
    data = f.read()

print len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', data))
```

On my machine, scanning a 3367861 byte GIF file that contains 500275 alpha chars, the regex code runs in about 20% of the time of my `.isalpha()` code.

Here's another solution that doesn't use regex (or other modules). It's not as fast as the `re.findall()` code, but surprisingly, it's faster than calling the `str.isalpha()` method. I guess that's because `str.isalpha()` is locale-dependent, which makes it a little more complicated.

```
alpha = frozenset('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
print sum(1 for c in data if c in alpha)
```

Comment: The `re.findall()` is indeed very fast!

Comment: @haavee: It certainly beats calling `re.sub()`. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring nice, this beats all other solutions in terms of timing

Comment: @PM2Ring turns out replaceing the frozenset by `alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split()` speeds this up by another 10%, which is only 10% slower than findall (on a 45MB file).

Comment: @miraculixx: Yes, it's faster, but unfortunately it's not correct. :) It returns a count of zero, because `'abc...XYZ'.split()` returns a list containing a single string. Replacing the `frozenset` with a correct `list` or `tuple` slows it right down to around 7x slower than using the `frozenset`.

Comment: @PM2Ring you are right, the `.split()` is not required, a simple string will do

Comment: On my machine a simple string is about 10% slower than the frozenset. But I'm only testing on a single file, which isn't really a fair test: a set can quickly determine if an item isn't a member, and can be slightly slower to verify members (due to possible hash collisions), whereas testing for string members requires a linear scan so non-members are the slowest to detect. And my GIF file is only 20% alpha chars.

Comment: Turns out your solutions beat all the others in terms of timing, I just ran a test on a 45MB input file, here are the [results](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/4345506d2ae8658bc9e0). In hindsight, considering overall complexity (time to write, skills required, time and space complexity) the straight-forward string to me seems the simplest, if not most pythonic approach of all _and_ yields a surprisingly good result -- as you pointed out earlier the quote by Donald Knuth certainly applies. QED. thanks for playing :-)

Comment: It's been fun. :) You should check out the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module if you want to do accurate & realistic timings.

Comment: re `timeit` yes, I know... I used that initially but didn't have the patience to work myself through the docs to make it work in the context of the test code. all in all I doubt there would be a large difference though as I'm averaging over 10 runs and my machine was idling during the tests. there's only so much one can cover in one night ;-) YMMV

Comment: Fair enough, `timeit` is a bit fiddly, but it's well worth getting familiar with. You've done well. BTW, you should check out the [SO Python Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) some time. It's quiet ATM, but it can get rather busy.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspect to this.. the first being the efficiency of reading from the file, the second being the efficiency of testing for alpha.  Here I am mainly considering the second part.. trying to make the test of each character as direct and simple as possible.  By directly checking the ascii values I'm eliminating most of the function calls and memory manipulations that are in your original solution and also most of the others.

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")

count = 0
for line in f.read():
    for i in line:
        a = ord(i)
        if a > 64 and a < 123 and not (a > 90 and a < 97):
            count += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work: it only reads a single char from the file.

Comment: You are right, I was not paying attention enough (I am at work) and broke it instead of making it better.. but this should work.  I do not have enough time right now to think about the best way to read the file, only look here for the character test...

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned earlier: you can't use the keyword `in` as a variable name. Once that's fixed, your code _does_ return the correct count, but it's very slow: over 40 times slower than my regex answer.

Comment: Cool I will take your word for it, I would not imagine a regex could ever be as fast as simple mathematical comparison (which the regex needs to do anyway) but I suppose that native python is much much slower than the compiled C of the regex library.  Although I write python these days I am a c programmer at heart and not used to this huge disparity in speed between the code you write yourself and the built-ins.  To me it is insane that solutions that call big complex functions can be slower than a simple integer comparison in a loop.

Comment: Fair enough. It is a bit disorienting at first, but you get used to it (I was writing C long before Python was invented). You eventually learn to utilise those parts of Python that run at C speed, like many of the operations that can work on a whole list at once, or to call module functions that are implemented in C. Note that many standard modules are implemented in Python, though fortunately a lot of the time-critical stuff _is_ done in C.

Comment: Also, `ord` is quite a bit slower than what you'd expect. In C it's virtually a free operation, but in Python the interpreter has to find the `ord` function in the `builtins` module and then call it on the string object. Of course `builtins.ord` is implemented in C, but it still has to do stuff that's not required in C, eg checking that its argument has a length of 1.